# What is an explicit bijection in combinatorics?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory, lo.logic, terminology, foundations

A standard way of demonstrating that two collections of combinatorial objects have the same cardinality is to exhibit a bijection between them. Browsing through some examples ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/769/exhibit-an-explicit-bijection-between-irreducible-polynomials-over-finite-fields), [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66221/explicit-bijection-between-ordered-trees-with-n1-vertices-and-binary-trees-wi), [yonder](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/bij.pdf)) quickly reveals that combinatorialists call such bijections *explicit*, presumably to differentiate them from other less palpable kinds of bijections. Wikipedia speaks of the method of [bijective proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_proof).

It seems that we have here a typical example of an informal mathematical notion that is quite familiar to most mathematicians, however it is difficult to pin down a proper and satisfying mathematical definition. I asked the local combinatorialists and did not really get a good answer.

**Question:** *What is a proper mathematical definition of an explicit bijection?*

Often we ask for an explicit bijection between two *families* of combinatorial objects, i.e., bijections $b_n : A_n \to B_n$, one for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Here $(A_n)_n$ and $(B_n)_n$ are two families of combinatorial objects, parametrized by $n$. The parameter need not be a single number.

Here are some *unsatisfactory* answers:

1. *"A bijection is explicit if it is computable."* This definition is too wide, because it allows silly algorithms that order combinatorial objects according to the layout of the sequences of bits that represent them, and use the order to establish a bijection. Bit representations typically have nothing to do with the combinatorial content of the objects under consideration.
2. *"A bijection is explicit if it can be written down as an expression."* This takes us back several centuries in terms of level of mathematical abstraction, and also varies a lot depending on what expressions are allowed. We really should be looking for a combinatorially meaningful notion, not a syntactic surrogate.
3. *"A bijection is explicit if we can give a constructive proof of its existence."* Well, a constructive proof certainly guarantees that a computable bijection exists, and can moreover be extracted from the proof, but this still feels too permissive. For example, we can always compose an explicit bijection so obtained with a computable automorphism of one of the sets, and still have a constructive proof. But such an automorphism could completely obfuscate the combinatorial structure of the set.
4. "Well-order $V_\omega$ (as all combinatorial objects easily live in it) and take the first bijection under the well ordering." Only a set theorist would have such thoughts. Again, we should strive for a definition which will be accepted as natural by combinatorialists.

Let me also say that I would prefer to *not* generalize the question to "what is an explicit thing?" At least in combinatorics "explicit bijections" are a well-established and useful notion, whereas mathematicians in general do not posses a universally agreed upon notion of "explicit thing".

**Supplemental:** After having a look at Igor Pak's [paper](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/ICM-paper9.pdf), I am somewhat convinced that computational complexity plays a certain role, but it cannot be the only answer (as Pak himself notes). For example, an explicit bijection may require factoring of numbers, which I feel most people would find unproblematic even though the computational complexity of factoring is not resolved.

Comment: That is one silly set theorist.

Comment: You know how they are, forcing things left and right.

Comment: in http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/ICM-paper9.pdf one finds some studies on the subject.

Comment: My feeling is that when one writes "We define an explicit bijection ..." one means a bijection whose computation depends only on the description of an individual object in the domain -- in particular the main dichotomy for me is between explicit and recursively defined bijections. Having said all that I'll also say that I'd be happier if "explicit bijection" were left as an informal notion! Especially since I suspect that I've been entirely inconsistent in its use.

Comment: Pak's paper I cited argues that an algorithm that computes a bijection as in 1) has to be "fast" in a well-defined sense.

Comment: Sounds like a good topic for a FPSAC talk :)

Comment: I have always wanted to learn about combinatorial species, but have never taken the time.  My impression is that this theory could provide one answer to your question.  Are you already familiar with it?

Comment: Species do seem to be relevant. Presumably one would first ask to work with a family of combinatorial objects A_S for finite sets S and be tasked to find bijections A_S—>B_S functorial under automorphisms of S (ie permutations). Maybe the families have further structure amongst the sets of different sizes, eg maps A_S \times A_T—->A_{S+T}, in which case you might ask your bijections to respect this structure too.

Comment: Why would you reject bit-sequence-based bijections? Those seem pretty explicit to me.

Comment: I think this question makes a mistake about what the terminology means. Specifically, the "explicit" in "explicit bijection" isn't a property of the bijection itself. It's more like the "explicit" in "explicit nudity"; a bijection (or nudity) is explicit if we show it, rather than implying that a bijection (or nudity) must exist. The same bijection may be explicit in one proof or left implicit in another.

Comment: For example, if I show an injection from A to B and an injection from B to A, then invoke the Schröder–Bernstein theorem to prove the cardinalities are equal, I am not using an explicit bijection. I've just shown that a bijection must exist. On the other hand, Schröder–Bernstein can be proved by constructing a bijection, and if I embed the construction into my proof directly and point to the resulting bijection, then I am using an explicit bijection. This bijection is explicit in the second proof, and it may be considered implicit in the first proof, but it's the same bijection either way.

Comment: it might be better to take different to the classical bit-wise computational complexities, e.g. the "real RAM model": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%E2%80%93Shub%E2%80%93Smale_machine

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t see what is the mathematical content of this question.  You want a precise definition of something which is used a lot but probably just for rhetorical emphasis (exPLIcit!).  Why?

Comment: @MonroeEskew Mathematicians like to formalize informal notions. A pay-off could be that (perhaps) down the line someone could use a formal definition to e.g. show that for some combinatorial objects of the same cardinality an explicit bijection can't be found. Who knows? I see no reason to censor the question itself.

Comment: Devil's advocate: _Godel proved that if we accept the axiom of constructibility in ZFC, then we can create an explicit formula that well-orders the real numbers_ https://mathoverflow.net/q/6593/4177

Comment: @JohnColeman I disagree with the idea of coming up with definitions “just for fun.”  When I write mathematics, I feel quite wrong if I define something new and the definition doesn’t cause any ink to be saved in a proof.

Comment: @MonroeEskew But this isn't "just for fun" -- explicit bijection is an *important* albeit informal notion in combinatorics. There very well might be mathematical significance in formalizing such a notion, in much the same way that e.g. defining elementary functions as (one possible) formalization of "closed form" function definitions is manifestly a mathematically fruitful definition.

Comment: I added the logic and category tags. I don't mean that the question ought to be tackled within either context, but in both model theory and category this is a natural question where contributors can help.

Comment: @JohnColeman, This phrase “explicit bijection” strikes me as akin to “direct proof” or “geometric argument.” The OP even includes a link to homework exercises as an example of usage. So while it may have some heuristic or pedagogical import, I don’t see the motivation for formalization without an application in mind.

Comment: @MonroeEskew: It looks like you are dead set on disputing the usefulness of the notion, but I would argue that it is *always* worthwhile formalizing a notion which is widely used, mostly agreed upon and recognized as important by a community. People publish papers in which the main result is to give an explicit bijection where it was already known that a bijection exists. Even only a partially satisfying answer might bring a new insight. Of course, I can't *guarantee* that it will, but history is on my side.

Comment: The more general term “explicit function” has been used more widely and for a longer time.  Eventually we thought about what this really means, and it wasn’t so clear.  There were different formalizations that had different uses.  On the one hand, we had things that could be generated by some ad-hoc but traditional collection of “elementary functions.”  Then there is the contrast with “implicit functions,” and the useful theorem of analysis, which nonetheless has little to do with things being “explicit” in the natural language sense of “fully and clearly expressed.”

Comment: So it could be, as in the above mentioned case, that there’s no single satisfactory formalization of an intuitive notion, but several options having different mathematical applications.

Comment: Sure, there might be several. Are you suggesting I ask the question several times? :-)

Comment: I don't think 'explicit bijection', any more than 'explicit construction', is or should be well defined; usually when people publish an 'explicit bijection' they mean something which is useful for some specific purpose. It might well be that to actually compute the bijection one needs to solve some hard problem, but nevertheless we agree to call it an 'explicit bijection' because it is useful. On the other hand, a bijection or construction involving brute-force search on a log-sized set (which is polynomial-time) might not count.

Comment: And maybe another (weak) argument against formalising the notion is the following: often it's interesting to have several different explicit bijections between the same sets, which are useful for different things - so at least, any formalism should be something which explains this.

Comment: @user2357112 that is very weak indeed. By that reasoning we shouldn’t have formalized the notion of continuous map. Or homomorphism. Or anything of which there can be several instances.

Comment: In any case. You are providing criteria for what an explicit bijection is or is not. You are not providing any arguments why we should not attempt to formalize the notion. In fact, I don’t see how a mathematician could ever object to making mathematical practice more precise.

Comment: Say you wrote something like, “let us call a bijection *explicit* if it is blah. Theorem: for all explicit bijections $f$, blah.” Then I’d have no objection. So what do you want to say about them?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do I want to say about what?

Comment: @AndrejBauer: Did you mean to reply to me or to user36212 there? Your reply sounds more applicable to user36212's comments.

Comment: To what extent might answers to this question be relevant to bijections in settings other than those we would normally call combinatorics?

Comment: @user2357112: sorry, my brain insists that all usernames of the form `userXYZ` represent the same generic "internet user". It was meant for the other user, yes.

Answer (score 27):

This is not at all intended as a complete answer to the question, but one criterion that feels important is that for a bijection $f$ to count as explicit, one shouldn't need to know in advance that there exists a bijection in order to prove that $f$ is a well-defined bijection. So for example if you order the elements of two sets $A$ and $B$ in some way that has nothing to do with why $|A|=|B|$, then you need to know that $|A|=|B|$ in order to conclude that the bijection that maps the $k$th element of $A$ to the $k$th element of $B$ is indeed a well-defined bijection.

I think this criterion rules out 1 and 4 (or would do if one could make it more formal, which might itself not be wholly easy).

Comment: Hmm, what about "map the $k$-th smallest element of $A$ to the $k$-th smallest element of $B$ or to the largest one if there is no $k$-th smallest one"? I am being somewhat tongue-in-cheek here, as we are clearly looking for a rule to follow in spirit rather than in letter. On the other hand, if we take this idea too far in the other direction, then a bijection $f : A \to B$ whose bijectivity is only proven using the pigeonhole principle (i.e., by showing that it is injective or surjective, and that $\left|A\right| = \left|B\right|$) should not count as explicit either. (Perhaps rightfully!)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the first part of your comment: how do we know that the map you define is a bijection?

Comment: I don't, but I know it *exists* :)

Comment: Ah, I didn't express my criterion clearly. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely an important aspect of the question. But note that we already have trouble formally expressing "one shouldn't need to know in advance that there exists a bijection". Given a proof, what does it mean that the proof "first proves existence"?

Comment: Indeed -- that is the difficulty I alluded to in my final sentence.

Comment: So for example, the map $V \to V^{**}$, $v \mapsto (\phi \mapsto \phi(v))$, is not explicit? (It goes without saying, I'm not a logician or a combinatorist, so maybe I'm being hare-brained.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Since we're discussing (finite) combinatorics, I suppose we ought to take a vector space over a finite field. If you can write down an explicit inverse, then we need not know ahead of time that $v \mapsto (\phi \mapsto \phi(v))$. I suspect this is going to revolve around a choice of base, isn't it?

Comment: @AndrejBauer So you don't just want an "explicit bijection", you actually want an "explicit bijection with explicit inverse"?

Comment: I always imagined that an explicit bijection would have an explicit inverse, but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 20):

One criterion not mentioned yet is **naturality in the categorical sense**, which can also be phrased as **equivariance with respect to permutation actions**.  This approach has been extensively developed by André Joyal and others, under the name of *combinatorial species*.

In almost all natural examples (I’m tempted to remove the “almost”), the sets $A_n$ and $B_n$ aren’t just $\mathbb{N}$-indexed families of sets; they also come with natural permutation actions, with $\Sigma_n$ acting on $A_n$ and $B_n$.  Equivalently, $A_\bullet$ and $B_\bullet$ can be seen as functors on the category $\mathrm{FinSet}_{\cong}$ of finite sets and isomorphisms; this representation is often clearest to work with.  E.g. if $A_n$ is “finite trees with $n$ leaves”, one can generalise it to a functor on $\mathrm{FinSet}_{\cong}$ by taking $A_X$ to be “finite trees with leaves labelled by $X$”; an isomorphism $\varphi : X \to Y$ gives an action $A_X \to A_Y$ by relabelling leaves.

One can then require the functions $f_n$ to be natural, in the categorical sense, with respect to this functoriality.  That is, for an isomorphism $\varphi : X \to Y$ of finite sets, and $a \in A_X$, one should have $f_Y(\varphi \cdot x) = \varphi \cdot (f_X a)$.  In terms of permutation actions, this is equivariance: $f_n(\sigma \cdot x) = \sigma \cdot f_n(x)$.

The effect of this, roughly, is to rule out constructions that involve arbitrary or non-uniform choices at any stage.  I think all examples that would traditionally be considered “natural” or “canonical” by combinatorialists are natural in this or some closely related sense — I’d be very interested to see a counterexample to that.  On the other hand, one can produce contrived examples that are natural in this sense without being “natural”: e.g. take some example with two different natural bijections $f$, $g$, and define a new one by using $f$ for even $n$, and $g$ for odd $n$.

Comparing to the other criteria suggested: this one is pretty much orthogonal to computational complexity.  It’s a bit linked to logical constructivity: there are metatheorems saying that anything definable in certain constructive logics must be natural in this sense.

Comment: The bijection between permutations and linear orders is not natural in this sense, but I do think it should be called explicit.

Comment: Maybe that means "explicit" is not an optimal word choice, either as a word or a concept.

Comment: I worry that combinatorialists also consider natural bijections between concrete sets $A$ and $B$, althought hat can be stuffed into spieces, I suppose, by having a family that is trivial everywhere, except in one index.

Comment: @MartinRubey: could you describe your example in a bit more detail?

Comment: This is exercise 1.1.10 in the book by Bergeron, Labelle and Leroux: the natural  action of the symmetric group $\mathfrak S_n$ on linear orders of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ has one orbit, whereas that the natural  action of the symmetric group $\mathfrak S_n$ on permutations of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ has as orbits the conjugacy classes.

Comment: Martin Rubey: Good point, that’s a very elementary example that’s not natural in the sense I stated.  It is still natural when stated in the right way — writing $L$ and $P$ for the species of linear orders and permutations respectively, we have $L \not \cong P$, but the standard bijection is natural as a bijection $L \times L \cong L \times P$ over $L$, which can be seen as an $L$-parametrised natural bijection $L \cong P$.  But yes, it shows that I overstated the claim of ubiquity; I’ll edit the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid that the assumption of having a symmetric group action on $A_n$ and $B_n$ is also rather demanding.  There are plenty of very beautiful natural bijections between various kinds of integer partitions, and there is no action in sight. An example might be Sylvester's bijection, see Igor Pak's slides mentioned in the question.

Comment: Whether or not this idea pans out, category theory is a good example of how questions of this type can be fruitful. Saunders Mac Lane said that he invented category theory to study natural transformations, and you can find usage of phrases like "natural transformation" and "natural isomorphism" prior to the original papers in category theory in the early 40s. The notion of "natural" in abstract algebra prior to category theory must have been an informal one. Category theory provided a way to formalize it.

Comment: @MartinRubey: Ah, interesting point — that example of Sylvester’s bijection is a rather different flavour.  I agree it’s much less clear how to fit that into this viewpoint.

Comment: Isn't the way out of some of these problems to consider L-species as well as B-species? By varying the base category of what needs 'fixed', the class of bijections thus obtained is still natural, but with respect to a specific context.

Comment: @JacquesCarette: I don't think so, because with $L$-species there is no requirement on the bijection anymore: an isomorphism of $L$-species has to be compatible with order preserving maps.  But any bijection on "unlabelled" objects like partitions satisfies this.  I think that naturality with respect to group actions is very important, but orthogonal to the property of being explicit.

Answer (score 14):

Here's an example (credit: Paul Russell) of the sort of bijection you want to rule out.

Question: Find an explicit bijection $f$ between the size-$k$ and size-$(k + 1)$ subsets of $\{1, 2, \dots, 2k+1\}$, such that $x \subset f(x)$ for all $x$.

Answer: Consider the bipartite graph with a vertex class $X$ for the size-$k$ subsets and a vertex class $Y$ for the size-$(k + 1)$ subsets; let edges $x, y$ denote $x \subset y$. The graph is regular, so a matching exists by Hall. Take the lexicographically first such matching (represented as a binary adjacency matrix).

If you try to rule this out by stipulating 'polynomial time' in your definition of explicit, then Russell's construction can be modified by replacing the last sentence with:

"Apply the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm to the initially empty matching"

Another attempt to rule out Russell's construction is to disallow someone from mentioning 'the set of all matchings', such as by type-theoretically restricting the answer to only mention sets of integers. But this approach doesn't work either, because finite sets can be encoded as integers.

Gowers' answer would rule this out if it could be made precise: by the time we invoke Hall, we know a matching exists. But if we didn't know about Hall's marriage theorem and avoided proving it until after applying the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm, we could 'cheat' the Gowers test. Also, a proof could be obfuscated, IOCCC-style, to hide the part that proves the existence of at least one matching.

What *would* rule out the Russell construction, whilst allowing the genuine explicit construction, is to stipulate that the bijection is computable with polynomial memory as a function of the description length of the individual objects being bijected: the full bipartite graph is exponential in $k$, whereas the objects (sets of integers) are expressible in $O(k \log k)$ symbols.

I'm going to suggest this definition unless anyone can provide a non-contrived example of an explicit combinatorial bijection that fails my test.

Comment: As for me, "the explicit regular bipartite graph with parts $A$ and $B$" is in general no worse than "the explicit bijection between $A$ and $B$". Analogously, the explicit graph on the ground set $V$ with odd degrees is no worse proof that $|V|$ is even than the coupling of vertices of $V$.

Comment: For the record, the solution passing the expliciticity test is https://mathoverflow.net/a/188298/3032 (and perhaps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8AEUfgQibc)

Comment: You wrote: "Consider the bipartite graph with a vertex class $X$ for the size-$k$ subsets and a vertex class $Y$ for the size-$k + 1$ subsets". It took me 10 seconds to realize that you meant the members of $X$ are the size-$k$ subsets and those of $Y$ are the size-$(k+1)$ subsets. $\qquad$

Comment: Surely "the description length of the individual objects being bijected" depends so much on the encoding that it shouldn't occur in a formal definition?

Comment: @LSpice It does depend on the encoding, yes, but if two encoding schemes are such that one is only polynomially more inefficient than the other, then it doesn't affect the definition of 'explicit bijection'. Also, any definition which includes 'computable' requires that the sets be encoded in some way.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher, right, but you could take that as my argument against computability being the relevant notion here.  After all, the elements of two sets in bijection can always be coded in such a way that the bijection is the identity on encodings.

Answer (score 11):

This should perhaps be a comment on the answer by Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine, but it's too long and might be relevant in connection with other answers as well. Long ago, Bruce Sagan and I wrote a paper,

Bijective proofs of two broken circuit theorems. 
J. Graph Theory 10 (1986), no. 1, 15–21,

in which we explicitly claimed, already in the title, to give bijective proofs. As far as I know, no one has yet objected to this claim, so I'll assume, in this answer, that the proofs given there are considered bijective. (Non-bijective proofs of the same results were known much earlier.)

Each of our results exhibits a bijection between two sets, say $A_G$ and $B_G$, associated to a finite graph $G$. As already hinted in the title, the definitions of these sets involve the notion of "broken circuit".  That notion, in turn, depends on a linear ordering of the set of edges of $G$. So the $G$ subscript in $A_G$ and $B_G$ should be understood as referring not just to the graph $G$ but to the graph together with such an ordering.

Unfortunately, a finite graph-with-edge-ordering has no nontrivial automorphisms except in some trivial cases.  In fact (again excepting trivial situations), a linear ordering of the edges is enough information to uniquely determine, in a purely combinatorial way, linear orderings of the finite sets $A_G$ and $B_G$. So we could, with the same information (and the same naturality) as in our construction, have defined the bijection between $A_G$ and $B_G$ that preserves the linear orderings. Yet no combinatorialist would call that a bijective proof.

Answer (score 9):

I would say that a bijection $\pi: A\to B$ is explicit, if for every $a\in A$ the image $\pi(a)$ can be computed without reference to $B$ itself.  More precisely, suppose that $A$ and $B$ are not known, but only an element $a\in A$, then it should still be possible to construct $\pi(a)$.

In particular, sorting $B$, or iterating over $B$ to find a particular object, is not possible with this definition.

On the other hand, this allows algorithms whose well-definedness or injectivity is not obvious from the algorithm.  I think that this is in fact desirable.

Let me contrast this definition with other concepts, which I believe
should be orthogonal to being explicit.

- computational complexity: a bijection may be computable in
  polynomial time and memory, but still be not explicit.

  For example, Dyck paths of semilength $n$ with exactly one valley are
  in bijection with subsets of size $2$ in $\{1,\dots,n\}$.  A
  non-explicit bijection which is computable in polynomial time is to
  fix an order on the Dyck paths, and an order on the subsets and match
  elements with the same index.
- simplicity: a bijection may be very complicated, but still be
  explicit.

  A (biased) example is Jagenteufel's bijection between Riordan paths
  and standard Young tableaux with three rows, whose row lengths are
  either all odd or all even, see Algorithm 3 in
  https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.03780, or Algorithm 3 in
  https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.03843 for a generalisation to fans of
  Riordan paths.

  Although this bijection is really complicated, it allows to deduce a
  refinement of the equinumeration result, that is otherwise
  unavailable.
- apparently bijective:

  The sweep maps on lattice paths were defined by Armstrong, Loehr and
  Warrington in https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1196.  It took quite a while
  to show that they are bijective, see Thomas and Williams
  https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01483.  I think that the maps were
  bijective already in June 2014, and did not become bijective in
  December 2015, but philosophy might disagree.

  I am sure there are also examples where the only known proof of bijectivity uses enumeration, but the map itself yields other properties.
- apparently well defined:

  Consider [Prüfer's bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) between $(n-2)$-tuples of integers in
  $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and labelled trees on $n$ vertices.  Although not
  hard to see, it is not a priori clear that given a tuple one actually
  obtains a tree: from the definition of the algorithm itself one might
  think that the result could be forest.

Comment: I wonder whether this is essentially the same as @Adam P. Goucher's answer!

Comment: (as my first example shows, it is not the same)

Answer (score 6):

I would like to adopt a slightly contrarian viewpoint:

> There is no formal mathematical definition of "explicit bijection."

Of course, I can't formally prove this assertion, but I would say that the reason you're having trouble finding a satisfactory formal definition is precisely because there isn't one.

A similar issue comes up in the Razborov–Rudich theory of [natural proofs](https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/rr.pdf).  Quoting from their paper:

> Note that the definition of a natural proof, unlike that of a natural combinatorial property, is not precise.  This is because while the notion of a property being explicitly defined in a journal paper is perfectly clear to the working mathematician, it is a bit slippery to formalize.  This lack of precision will not affect the precision of our general statements about natural proofs because they will appear only in the form "there exists (no) natural proof…", and should be understood as equivalent to "there exists (no) natural combinatorial property $C_n$…"

Taking a cue from the above, I think that what may be more productive than trying to pin down an exact definition of an explicit bijection is finding **sufficient** conditions for being an explicit bijection.  I say this because I have a secret agenda: performing [automated searches for explicit bijections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288051/automated-search-for-bijective-proofs).
For this purpose, I think it would be useful to compile a list of "atomic" components of an explicit bijection and say that if one combines no more than $x$ such components in certain specified ways, then the resulting bijection (or map, if we don't know in advance that it is bijective) is explicit.

By the way, here's an analogous issue from recreational mathematics.  What does it mean to say that a Sudoku puzzle (let's assume that it has a unique solution) can be "solved without guessing"?  I don't think that there is a canonical answer to this question, because what looks like guessing to you or me might just be a "standard trick" to a sufficiently powerful brain.  On the other hand, it is possible to compile a specific long list of known tricks, and then you can automate the generation of "Sudokus solvable without guessing."

Comment: Of course a sufficiently useful sufficient condition would already be quite an accomplishment. I never imagined we could come up with a formal definition that would cover all the corners and make everyone happy. Regarding Sudoku, I think it's something like: "using these five simple strategies for making the next step (the ones that normal humans use) we cannot get stuck in whatever way we use them".

Comment: The most interesting idea I've seen for Sudoku is Wei-Hwa Huang's "Sledgehammer": https://onigame.livejournal.com/20626.html  I think that for combinatorics, one would want to do something similar. Start by defining the two types of combinatorial data structures that you want to biject. Then specify a short list of available atomic operations. It's similar to defining an algorithm except that the point is to *avoid too much generality*. This is tough to do, at least psychologically, since mathematicians have a conditioned reflex to generalize.

Comment: @TimothyChow: concerning (semi)automated search for bijections, my biggest obstacle is currently that I need a definition for "simplicity" of a map.  A requirement is that the simplicity can be determined for a given algorithm. Evidently, it should distinguish some simple maps from not so simple ones, eg. inverse of a permutation should be simpler than Foata's map http://www.findstat.org/Mp00067. I would prefer a definition that depends only on the map, and not the algorithm.

Comment: Of course, computational complexity (say, worst case among objects of a given size) comes to mind, but this seems both hard to determine in praxis, and does not seem to distinguish many maps.  In fact, what is the complexity of Foata's map?

Comment: I don't know if this helps you guys at all, but in the programming language community there is [bidirectional programming](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/papers/lenses-etapsslides.pdf) where people design programming languages in which *every* algorithms is invertible by design.

Comment: Does it make sense to talk about one bijection being more explicit than another?  I'm of the opinion that it does, and that this supports @TimothyChow's position.

Comment: Wouldn't any suggestion of the form "if one combines no more than $x$ such components … then the resulting bijection … is explicit" automatically run up against some version of the [sorites paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox)?  (EDIT:  I just saw @RussWoodroofe's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323779/what-is-an-explicit-bijection-in-combinatorics#comment808707_323875), which I think provides a way around this; one can have a degree of explicitness without an (ha!) explicit binary cut-off.)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion has quite some overlap with other comments and also @gowers answer:

Let $A$, $B$ be two sets. An **explicit bijection** between $A$ and $B$ is a deterministic algorithm taking elements of $A$ as input and for which outputs are elements of $B$, such that an analysis of the algorithm yield its bijectivity.

Several notes:

- In most cases I have been looking at, the sets $A$ and $B$ were finite.
- A typical way of satisfying this criterion is to provide two deterministic algorithms $A \to B$ and $B \to A$ and showing that they are inverses of each other. Or showing that both are injective. I would also call this "explicit" though one might need to slightly reword to include this situation.
- I did not include anything about complexity of the algorithm because I do not think its actual computation time is relevant for it being "explicit".
- I have often seen the following relaxation, namely that one knows already that $|A| = |B|$, and only deduces injectivity or surjectivity from the algorithm. The problem with this relaxation is that it would allow just listing the elements of both sets...

Comment: I don't see how this works with, say, A and B being two isomorphic finite groups - then certainly there is an algorithm giving a bijection, but it would be in general very ugly. An example of this would be 
https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0113 - it's not something one would call explicit...

Comment: I disagree, because there are explicit bijections, which are beautiful, but bijectivity was very hard to prove or only follows because one knows for different reasons that the sets in question have the same cardinality.

Comment: I think this falls under my first counter-example. But more importantly, how do you precisely define "such that an analysis of the algoithm yields its bijectivity"?

Comment: If you can't prove that an algorithm implements a bijection, it just means that you can't prove that you have an explicit bijection.  I don't think it has anything to do with the *definition* of an explicit bijection.