# Is this notion of "concrete bijection" transitive?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic, model-theory

*This question looks at the same intuition as, but expressed via a different formal notion than, a couple earlier questions of mine ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/q/424136/8133), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467244/is-this-type-of-definable-bijective-solution-of-combinatorial-identities-symme)). Basically, I'm playing around with using model theory to provide a precise meaning of "bijective proof" in combinatorics. Below, all formulas/sentences are first-order.*

---

Given a sentence $\varphi$ in the language of a single binary relation symbol $R$ and a natural number $n$, let $[\varphi]_n$ be the set of *isomorphism types of* models of $\varphi$ with size $n$. This question is about a (seeming) refinement of the equivalence relation $$\varphi\sim\psi:\quad\forall n([\varphi]_n=[\psi]_n).$$

Roughly speaking - the details are tedious, so I've put them below the fold - suppose $\varphi\sim\psi$. A **concrete bijection between $\varphi$ and $\psi$** is a pair $(\lambda,\theta)$ with $\lambda$ a sentence (in an arbitrary language) and $\theta$ a formula (in a language related to that of $\lambda$), such that the following hold for each $n>0$:

- There is at least one model of $\lambda$ with size $n$ up to isomorphism.
- If $\mathcal{A}$ is a structure consisting of $(i)$ the set $\{1,...,n\}$ expanded to be a model of $\lambda$, $(ii)$ a further set of objects $U$ representing each element of $[\varphi]_n$, and $(iii)$ a further set of objects $V$ representing each element of $[\psi]_n$, then $\theta^{\mathcal{A}}$ is a bijection between $U$ and $V$. (This part is vague; see below for details.)

The motivating example is the following: there is a concrete bijection between "$R$ partitions the universe into $\le 2$ classes" and "$R$ partitions the universe into pairs-or-singletons" using the linear order axioms for $\lambda$, since we can say when an instance of the former type "turns into" an instance of the latter by "rotating the Young diagram."

Write $\varphi\approx\psi$ if there is a concrete bijection between $\varphi$ and $\psi$. While trivially symmetric (compare with the second above-linked question), transitivity is not obvious to me:

> **Question 1**: Is $\approx$ transitive?

Separately, I'm curious if it actually refines $\sim$ at all:

> **Question 2**: Do $\sim$ and $\approx$ coincide?

Obviously an affirmative answer to 2 gives the same for 1, but rather sadly.

---

### Concrete bijections, rigorously

The only aspect of the description of "concrete bijection" given above that wasn't rigorous was the nature of the structures $\mathcal{A}$ considered in the second bulletpoint. Precisely, we're looking at all structures $\mathcal{A}$ such that:

- The underlying set of $\mathcal{A}$ is broken into three pieces named by unary predicates, $X\sqcup U\sqcup V$, with $\vert X\vert=n$, $\vert U\vert=\vert[\varphi]_n\vert$, and $\vert V\vert=\vert[\psi]_n\vert$. *(And remember that $\vert[\varphi]_n\vert=\vert[\psi]_n\vert$.)*
- On the $X$-part, we have relations turning it into a model of $\lambda$. These relations do not hold anywhere else.
- Additionally, we have two ternary relation symbols $E\subseteq U\times X^2$ and $F\subseteq V\times X^2$ such that (conflating structures and isomorphism types) $$[\varphi]_n=\{(X; E(u,-,-): u\in U\}\quad\mbox{and}\quad [\psi]_n=\{(X; F(v,-,-): v\in V)\}.$$

The second bulletpoint in the definition of concrete bijections, then, says: "For every $\mathcal{A}$ of the above type, $\theta$ defines a bijection between the $U$- and $V$-parts." (And this is required to hold for all $n$, with $\lambda$ and $\theta$ not depending on $n$.)

Intuitively, a concrete bijection between $\varphi$ and $\psi$ is a way to, given any finite set $X$ and any set of representatives of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ on $X$, build in a first-order way a bijection between those sets of representatives ... possibly using some "auxiliary" structure on $X$ itself (e.g. a linear order). There are various natural tweaks we could further consider - most obviously, it's tempting to demand that $\theta^\mathcal{A}$'s behavior on $[\varphi]_n,[\psi]_n$ be independent of the choice of representatives - but for now I'll stick to the rather weak notion above.

Comment: I know nothing about models, but I'd be interested how the above is related to my personal (vague) favourite idea of "explicit bijection" in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323779/what-is-an-explicit-bijection-in-combinatorics/323827#323827 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324117/formalize-ignorance !

Comment: Given concrete bijections defined by sentences $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, can we simply create a new language which has all the relations used in the definition of $\lambda_1$ and separately all the relations used in the definition of $\lambda_2$, and then consider the sentence $\lambda_1 \wedge \lambda_2$ in that language?

Comment: @WillSawin The issue is the $\theta$-part; remember that a concrete bijection is a pair $(\lambda,\theta)$ not just the $\lambda$-part on its own. Basically, via its $\theta$ a concrete bijection between $\varphi$ and $\psi$ makes reference to $\varphi$-expansions and $\psi$-expansions, and similarly a concrete bijection between $\psi$ and $\rho$ makes reference to $\psi$-expansions and $\rho$-expansions. Now if  want to try to combine these to get a concrete bijection between $\varphi$ and $\rho$, I seem to need to existentially quantify over the now-forgotten $\psi$-expansions along the way.